# Add new record via WCF and LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql

I'm using WCF with Linq-to-SQL in my application. How do I add a new record tp the WF table?

Comment: This question needs a lot more details before it can be answered. If you're "using Linq-to-SQL" *in your application*, then that will hardly use WCF. On the other hand, if your database layer is behind a WCF service, you're hardly using Linq-to-sql *in your application*. Can you please elaborate a bit more? Generally, it helps if you describe what you've tried, what didn't work, your hypothesis to the cause of the problems, etc.

Comment: I need in my application to connect to my database so I used WCF service and connect with my database via ORM which is Linq. Now while im using this WCF service which is service1, I want to add a new record to a table in my DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will create an new WF object and insert it into a database where db is the databaseContext this would be in your WCF, I presume that you have dbml file setup with the WF table on it?

```
using System.Linq;

// create context    
using(DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext ())
{
    // create table entry
    WF entry= new WF();
    // set values of the table 
    entry.someColumnName = "something";
    db.WFs.InsertOnSubmit(entry);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have. Linq file. but how can I reach this from the .cs file? you said this in in WCF. I have to insert from .cs. or u mean I write the above code in method, and call this method in .cs file(windowsApplication). Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can create a method and then call that method from the wcf when you need it. If you have some WCF code then post it in your question. I also added the using statement you will need to access Linq in your cs. You may also need to add a using statemnt to your cs depending on your namespace structure.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't see the class DBDataContext.

Comment: @Sofy Where did you write that code? In your application or in the WCF service code?

Comment: I tried the above code in my application, but i also tried to write a method in WCF public void fill_WF(bool flag){DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext();WF entry = new WF();entry.someColumnName = "something";db.SubmittedFeedbacks.InsertOnSubmit(entry);db.SubmitChanges();}

Comment: both didn't recognize DBDataContext, even I used using system.Data.Linq; and using system.linq; Thank you

Comment: DBDataContext is the name of my dbml, yours will be different, open your dbml file then view the properties window and you will see the name of your database context in the "name" field.

Comment: Ok, thanks. but waht this instruction:db.SubmittedFeedbacks.InsertOnSubmit(entry); it cant find SubmittedFeedbacks at all.

Comment: Sorry Sofy that was a typo i have updated the line in the example.